# How do I enable mysqli for my PHP script?

Tags: php, mysqli

I am trying to use mysqli to connect to my MySQL database using mysqli_connect(). However, whenever I grab a reference to my .php file that attempts to connect to the database, it throws a fatal error:

Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function mysqli_connect()

I read that you must delete a semi-colon from php.ini, but my PHP7 folder does not contain a strictly php.ini file. It only has php.ini-development and production; deleting the semi-colons for anything related to mysqli does nothing. For the record, I am also not using XAMPP, or any web server applications of the likes. Instead, I am using PHP's command to run a server:

php -S localhost:8000

I am not sure if that has anything to do with it.
Furthermore, when I run phpinfo(), it states:

Loaded Configuration File   (none)

How do I get mysqli to work?

Comment: when you install php you get `php-development.ini` and `php-prodcution.ini`. You need to rename one of the two (depending on whether the environment is for development or  production) to `php.ini`

Answer (score 21):

If you are using PHP 7 and Ubuntu 16.04 then you can do this:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install php-mysql
sudo service apache2 restart
```

It'll automatically enable the mysqli extension for the PHP because connect using mysql is deprecated in PHP 7.

If not an Ubuntu user then you can just rename php-prodcution.ini file to php.ini and enable the extension by removing semicolon in the php.ini file.

```
extension=php_mysqli.so
```

Don't forget to restart the server (Apache or Ngnix) after updating php.ini file.

Comment: php_mysqli.dll on Ubuntu? Really?

Comment: this is clearly wrong for ubuntu. dll files are for Windows . . .

Comment: Thanks, both of you. It's added mistakenly.

Answer (score 5):

You have to rename one file (php.ini-development or php.ini-production) to `php.ini`. That's the file you have to configure. Normally you should rename the `production` file.

Answer (score -2):

There are 2 things to be done if you are using 5.3.0 and later version of php.
1. Uncomment and set right path to extension_dir = "ext"
Basically set the path where you find ext filder in php even if its in same folder from where you are running php-cgi.ex

2. uncomment mysqli library extention 
   extension=mysqli

Note: uncommenting in this php.ini file is by removing starting ; from the line.